# Android Application quits after saving picture

Tags: android

Hi Guys My application quits just after the image is saved, I cannot see why, Please help? 
This is the button pressed method, after the picture is taken I press save, The image gets saved where it needs to be saved but the application just quits after I press save, It does not say "Not Responding", it just quits

```
    cam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            leakerID = leakId.getText().toString();
            String direc = "/e3softData/DCIM/";
            String fileName = leakerID+".jpg";
            // get the path to sdcard
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // to this path add a new directory path
            File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + direc);
            // create this directory if not already created
            dir.mkdir();

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

            File file = new File(dir, fileName);
            String f = file.toString();
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(f));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }   
    });
```

Comment: That's the tricky part, I don't have my tab on me and I am no fan of the emulator, I am sending the apk to my friends phone then he gives me feedback via sms

Comment: Please provide logcat.. so much tricky.. i got amazed :P

Comment: On the emulator it keeps saying camera not responding, so I don't even get there, further I will provide the logcat when I get to my tab and can connect it that should be within the next hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/e3softData/DCIM/");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir();
                }
                String fileName = leakerID+".jpg";
                output = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
```

Comment: Please do not supply code without commentary of what you're showing us.

Comment: Thanx man that solved my problem, What exactly did I do wrong if I may ask?